# How to preg_match specific javascript element to get values?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Example:

```
<script>
var images= new Array();
   lstImages.push("one");
   lstImages.push("two");
   lstImages.push("three");
</script>
```

How to preg_match so I can get result for values one, two, three ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = '<script>
var images= new Array();
   lstImages.push("one");
   lstImages.push("two");
   lstImages.push("three");
</script>';

$matches = array();
if(preg_match_all('#lstImages.push\("(.*)"\);#', $html, $matches))
{
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

This will return this :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'one' (length=3)
  1 => string 'two' (length=3)
  2 => string 'three' (length=5)
```

So, there we are basicaly searching for the string `lstImages.push("something here");`

Then you just have to exploit this like that : `$items = $matches[1];`

Then all your items are in `$items`

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfectly fit my need.